# PeriodicWorkRequest with compileSdkVersion 21

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to add PeriodicWorkRequest on an old project. That uses compileSdkVersion 21. I can not update compileSDKVersion.

This is my build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0')
//{
    //exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
//}
implementation ('android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1')
{
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-compat"
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-core-ui"
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-fragment"
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-core-utils"
}
```

I get these errors:

> Android resource linking failed
>
> build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:408: AAPT: error: attribute android:directBootAware not found.

Is it possible to include WorkManager in my project?

Thanks

Comment: "I can not update compileSDKVersion." -- why not? You should always be compiling against the latest production API level (in this case, 30). It looks like `WorkManager` requires a `compileSdkVersion` of at least 24, based on [the attribute from your error message](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#directBootAware).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager
from their documentation WorkManager uses AlarmManager for api 14-22 and Job Scheduler for api 23+, but their first package requires api 24. Nice....

Comment: it seems that you are able to use android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha07 for api21